wrapping ctypes.Structure inside a class
I want to be able to pass a structure to some c-code and am using ctypes.structure. I have a simple working example that takes an input array and squares the elements and outputs as an array. However, I'm having problems putting this into a python class to create a wrapper routine.
The simple c-code is:
test.c
struct DATA;

typedef struct DATA {
    int n;
    double *ina;
    double *outa;
} DATA;

void square_array2(DATA *data) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<data->n; i++) {
        data->outa[i] = data->ina[i]*data->ina[i];
    }
}

I compile this with
gcc -shared -fPIC test.c -o test.so

In a jupyter notebook I have:
import importlib
import numpy as np
import ctypes
from ctypes import CDLL, POINTER
from ctypes import c_size_t, c_double
from wurlitzer import pipes, STDOUT
%reload_ext wurlitzer

testlib = CDLL('test.so')

n=5
ina  = np.linspace(1.0,5.0,n)
outa = np.zeros(n,np.float64)

class Data(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("n", ctypes.c_int),
                ("ina", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)),
                ("outa", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))]

data = Data(n,np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(ina),np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(outa))

print("initial array",ina)
testlib.square_array2.restype = None
testlib.square_array2(ctypes.byref(data))
print("final array",outa)

This all works fine from within a jupyter notebook.
The part that doesn't work is putting this
into a python class wrapper.
Here is my wrapper attempt that does not work:
import ctypes

from ctypes import CDLL, POINTER 
from ctypes import c_size_t, c_double, c_int 
from io import StringIO 
from wurlitzer import pipes, STDOUT


class Data(ctypes.Structure): 
    _fields_ = [("n", ctypes.c_int), 
                ("ina", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)), 
                ("outa", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))]

class testClib(Data):   #attempting to inherit the Data class.

    def __init__(self):
        # load the library
        self.lib = CDLL("test.so")
    
    def square_array2(self,ina,outa):

        n, = ina.shape
    
        # !!! the line that doesn't work....
        data = Data(n,np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(ina),np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(outa))
    
        out = StringIO()

        with pipes(stdout=out, stderr=STDOUT):
                
            self.lib.square_array2.restype = None
            self.lib.square_array2(ctypes.byref(data))
        
        stdout = out.getvalue()
        print(stdout)
        print(ina)
        print(outa)

I call this routine from my jupyter notebook with the command:
ctest.square_array2(ina,outa)

The error message on execution is:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[51], line 3
      1 # lets add this in a wrapper routine
----> 3 ctest.square_array2(ina,outa)

File ~/WORK/PYTHONLIB/ctypesTEST/ctypesTEST3.py:46, in testClib.square_array2(self, ina, outa)
     42 def square_array2(self,ina,outa):
     44     n, = ina.shape
---> 46     data = Data(n,np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(ina),np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(outa))
     48     out = StringIO()
     50     with pipes(stdout=out, stderr=STDOUT):

TypeError: too many initializers


# !!! the line that doesn't work....
To help in troubleshooting the issue, you may want to add details on what does not work. As the two calls to the Data constructor are equivalent, I would start by comparing the parameters passed to the ctypes constructor for Data in either case.

Hi, I think some of the problem is my ignorance on how to properly inherit and use the Data class into the testClib class. I'm not sure how to access the fields construction. Rob

I can't reproduce the failure.  Make a [mcve] that is a single code block that can be copy/paste/run without changes to reproduce the problem.  Note that testClib has no need to derive from Data.

Code and error are not in sync: probably you ran an unsaved version of the code (not in the question: Data with fewer _fields_). Anyway, also check: [SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer) for a common pitfall when working with CTypes (calling functions).

In creating a more minimal version of my question I think I hit on the answer.
In my jupyter notebook I have the following.
import numpy as np
import ctypes

# link to the python wrapper library 
import ctypesTEST4 as ct

With the next block being the first test that always worked:
# Example 1 -- sending a structure in the python code

# set up an in and out array

n=5
ina  = np.linspace(1.0,5.0,n)
outa = np.zeros(n,np.float64)

# link to the c-library
testlib = ctypes.CDLL('test.4.so')

# set the data structure 

class Data(ctypes.Structure):
     _fields_ = [("n", ctypes.c_int),
                ("ina", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)),
                ("outa", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))]

data = Data(n, np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(ina), np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(outa))


testlib.square_array.restype = None
testlib.square_array(ctypes.byref(data))
print("initial array",ina)
print("  final array",outa)

This generates the answer

initial array [1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
final array [ 1.  4.  9. 16. 25.]

The next bock is the test that now works...
In jupyter I have the block:
# Example 2 -- using a wrapper routine to do the same thing
# create an instance of the class 
ctest = ct.testClib() 
ctest.square_array(ina,outa)
print("initial array",ina)
print("  final array",outa)

The answer being

initial array [1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
final array [ 1.  4.  9. 16. 25.]

The wrapper class looks like this
import numpy as np
import ctypes

class Data(ctypes.Structure):
     _fields_ = [("n", ctypes.c_int),
                ("ina", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)),
                ("outa", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))]
     

class testClib():
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        # load the library
        self.lib = ctypes.CDLL("test.4.so")

    def square_array(self,ina,outa):

        n, = ina.shape
        
        data = Data(n,np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(ina),np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(outa))
        
        self.lib.square_array.restype = None
        self.lib.square_array(ctypes.byref(data))
            

The c code looks like this

struct DATA;

typedef struct DATA
{
  int n;
  double *ina;
  double *outa;
} DATA;


void square_array(DATA *data)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<data->n; i++)
      {
        data->outa[i] = data->ina[i]*data->ina[i];
      }
}

Again I compiled that with

gcc -shared -fPIC test.4.c -o test.4.so

This is calling the python wrapper library

As mentioned, the two calls to the Data class constructor are identical and the scope is equivalent, so it's worth looking at the parameters used in both calls.
You get a TypeError: too many initializers error, which seems to indicate that something is wrong when initializing the Data structure
ctypes structures can be initialized by passing values for the attributes to the constructor, which is what you are doing in your example
I have tried to reproduce vaguely your scenario and got this in the interactive interpreter:
>>> n = 5
>>> x = c_double(3.45); ina = pointer(x)
>>> y = c_double(9.23); outa = pointer(y)
>>> data = Data(n, ina, outa)
>>> data.n; data.ina.contents; data.outa.contents
5
c_double(3.45)
c_double(9.23)

which is good. If I add a parameter for which there is no attribute in the structure, I get the infamous TypeError: too many initializers
>>> data = Data(n, ina, outa, 90)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: too many initializers

Notably, I do not get the same error for type/argument mismatch, so I think this can be a good start. Why more than three arguments are fed to the Data constructor
